# Can't figure out why I'm getting Server errors from my PHP code

Tags: php, facebook, plugins, registration

On this PHP page I'm parsing a signed request that I receive from the facebook registration plug in that I'm using. There is a problem with the location property from the signed request $response object that I'm saving, but I can't figure out what it is. I get one of two errors: 1. **The address wasn't understood, firefox doesnt know how to open the address because the protocol (s) isn't associated with any program.** When I get that error the browser bar shows this: **s:18:"New York,New York";** which is the value of the location property that I'm trying to save into a variable. The second error:  **The requested URL /~spilot/spilot.koding.com/website/New York,New York** was not found on this server. Again, "New York New York", being the value of the location property that I'm trying to save into a variable. Below is my code for the entire php page:

```
<?php

//code omitted here that decodes and checks the JSON signature of the signed request. It has been tested and I know the problem isn't there. 

    if ($_REQUEST) 
    {
    $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'],
    FACEBOOK_SECRET);
    }

//this is where I save the values from the registration form into php variables. 

    $name = $response["registration"]["name"]; 
    $email = $response["registration"]["email"]; 
    $password = $response["registration"]["password"];
    $uID = $response["user_id"];

    // The problem is with the location variable.
```

//I want it to store to my database as a string and not an object which is why I use //serialize(), but I get the aforementioned errors whether I use serialize or not.

```
    $location = $response["registration"]["location"]["name"];

    $city = serialize($location);

    ?>

// I'm using the Parse Cloud Server to power the back end and I have to connect with parse using javascript. 

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var password = '<?php echo $password ?>';

    var name = '<?php echo $name ?>';

    var uID = '<?php echo $uID ?>';

    var email = '<?php echo $email ?>';

    var location = '<?php echo $city ?>';

             //Initialize the Parse SDK!


          Parse.initialize("ivHLAO7z9ml1bBglUNuPSgcWabXe3UeE********","gNeGt04lU7xcew8********qc4POVhBsIBSCVj");
               var User = new Parse.User();
                User.set("password",  password);                    
                User.set("username",  name);
                User.set("uID", uID);
                User.set("email", email);
                User.set("location", $city);

          User.signUp(null, { 
          success: function(user) 
          { 
          alert("User signed up!"); 


          } 
          });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing this:

```
var location = '<?php echo $city ?>';
```

to perhaps

```
var city = ...
```

Your error suggests that this being treated as the equivalent of

```
window.location = ...;
```

which for some reason is coming out of PHP as a `serialize()`' string. Since a serialized string from PHP isn't a valid url, you get that "unknown" protocol error.

Comment: Gosh. It worked. Thanks so much. I had no idea what the problem was. You've been a huge help.